# how to make the background the same as the div size in css

Tags: css, web, web-deployment

I'm developing a website and I need to know how can I make the background the same size of the div in the css  .. I'm trying to make the BG size auto but it doesn't  works > So does any one know a solution for that
!!

Thanks

Comment: #header {
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 40px 0;
 position: relative;
    background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size:auto;
    

}

Comment: could you include your html as well? thanks..

Comment: Update your question with your `HTML` and `CSS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#header { 
      background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{  
 background: url(bgimage.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry,, I tried it but the BG doesn't fit into the div coz the BG size very larger than the div size